# Problem: Ubuntu 22.04 rule list replacing after Network Card reloading

Tags: networking, network-manager, 22.04

I have a fresh installation of ubuntu server 22.04. By default, the ip rule list outputs

```
0: from all lookup local
32766: from all lookup main
32767: from all lookup default
After that I add the rules

ip rule add from 192.168.12.3/32 table mobile2
ip rule add to 192.168.12.3/32 table mobile2
```

After that everything is fine and the output of the ip rule list command

```
0: from all lookup local
32764: from all to 192.168.12.3 lookup mobile2
32765: from 192.168.12.3 lookup mobile2
32766: from all lookup main
32767: from all lookup default
```

If after that I disconnect and connect the network cable, the ip rule list output goes back to the first state. In ubuntu 20.04 there is no such problem and the ip rule list stays.

Calling the command ifconfig down/up causes the same effect.

How avoid situation where we changing the "rule list" after "ifconfig down"

Answer (score 1):

Just add:

```
"ManageForeignRoutingPolicyRules=false"
```

to `[Network]` area in `/etc/systemd/networkd.conf`.